# Is there a way to increase sheet index in excel formula by rows?

Tags: excel

I want to include columns from another sheets in Excel in formula. My formula is `=Sheet1!$A$1`
I need a list number to increase by rows automatically
For example:
row 1 `=Sheet1!$A$1`
row 2 `=Sheet2!$A$1`
row 3 `=Sheet3!$A$1`
row 4 `=Sheet4!$A$1`

Is there any way to update a formula so it automatically takes values from the next list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet"&ROW(A1)&"'!A1")
```